# How do I make the SpatiaLite banner go away under Django manage.py?

Tags: django, spatialite

Every time I run `manage.py` I get the SpatiaLite banner.

```
SpatiaLite version ..: 3.0.0-beta   Supported Extensions:
- 'VirtualShape'    [direct Shapefile access]
- 'VirtualDbf'      [direct Dbf access]
- 'VirtualText'     [direct CSV/TXT access]
- 'VirtualXL'       [direct XLS access]
- 'VirtualText'     [direct CSV/TXT access]
- 'VirtualNetwork'  [Dijkstra shortest path]
- 'RTree'       [Spatial Index - R*Tree]
- 'MbrCache'        [Spatial Index - MBR cache]
- 'VirtualSpatialIndex' [R*Tree metahandler]
- 'VirtualFDO'      [FDO-OGR interoperability]
- 'SpatiaLite'      [Spatial SQL - OGC]
PROJ.4 Rel. 4.7.1, 23 September 2009
GEOS version 3.2.2-CAPI-1.6.2
```

Even when I'm trying to `dumpdata` (screwing up my dump), and it also appears whenever `runserver` serves a HTML request (paging away request history).  How do I suppress this identifying message?

Answer (score 0):

As of spatialite 2.2, the banner is always present, no option to remove it.

In src/shell/shell.c:

```
spatialite_init (1);
```

1 meaning verbose.

If you want to remove it, change the value to 0 and recompile spatialite or update to libspatialite and spatialite-tools to 4.2.0 which includes the -silent option.

Either way, you'd have use spatialite binary directly, since 
`python manage.py dbshell`
does not accept options to be passed to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a shell function to remove the banner:

```
sp(){ spatialite $* | head -n +14 ; }
```

But I didn't see that it was in the Django framework. Sorry for the noise.